# ui-router, using default parameter if nothing was passed in the url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there any way to handle both `/silukin/:start`  and `/silukin`, with condition if **`:start`** param not passed, then use **'1'** by default?

```
.state('app.silukin', {
        url: "/silukin/:id",
        views: {
            'menuContent1': {
                templateUrl: "templates/silukin.html",
                controller: 'SilukinCtrl',

            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this [API Reference](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider). (click the $state - Provider). With latest UI-Router we can use new attributes for state defintion:

```
.state('app.silukin', {
    url: "/silukin/:id",
    views: {
        'menuContent1': {
            templateUrl: "templates/silukin.html",
            controller: 'SilukinCtrl',

        }
    },
    // define a parameter's default value
    params: {
      id: { value: "defaultValue" }
    }
```

Check the [API reference](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider) for more details

**params** *(optional)*     object

> A map which optionally configures parameters declared in the url, or defines additional non-url parameters. For each parameter being configured, add a configuration object keyed to the name of the parameter.
>
> Each parameter configuration object may contain the following properties:
>
> - value
> - array
> - squash 
>     -- *(see more in that resource)*

Comment: I'm glad you're teaching people about default params, @RadimKöhler